# How pass props into HOC from connect's HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Proto code:

```
LoginComponentWrapper = connect(
    state => ({ write: userSelector(state) }),
    { submit }
)(LoginComponent);
```

and then pass into HOC :

```
export default Proxy(LoginComponentWrapper, {
    name:  // here  I want access to  write props form connect
});
```

How can I do this ?

May be another form question : 
How pass into HOC props from connect () ?

Comment: You should be able to pass name prop to the connected component. What is being the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapStateToProps` and allow it to accept extra params:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
   write: state.write,
   submit: ownProps.submit
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
LoginComponentWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps)(props => <LoginComponent {...props} submit={submit}/>);
```